# How to recompile my program using code block

Tags: c++, algorithm, compilation, cmake

When I finish executing my `c++` code, I need to compile again. But, I don't want to close my window of return, I wanna compile again to compare my results.

How can I do this?

Comment: Run it from the directory where it is, instead of hitting Code::Blocks' run button. And I don't understand, why did you use the cmake tag.

Comment: i thought i would need use cmake to do this.

Comment: and i can not understand yet how can i do this.

Comment: When you compile, an exe file is created. If you access project's options, you should find out where the exe is outputted. By default, it's `<your project's directory>\bin\Debug` (or `Release` for last one, if you are compiling release version).

Comment: i need to use with a one botton,i can not do this mechanically.

Comment: I compile my program.I have my file exe (c:\luciana\pvi\bin\debug\pvi.exe).Now, i want to change my input,change a number,for example.  Soon,i need to compile again. But i will try to compile again,this program is closed. I dont want this. I want to compile another time,without clossing my output. I want to compile another time,have another outputted. So,when i have two outputted,i can compare my two results.This clearer?

Comment: Then start the Debug version outside Code::Blocks and rebuild the Release version. Those will be two different versions running, and you can compare the results.